# wrapInner() of body until a specified element

Tags: jquery, html, css, wrapinner

Using the below HTML:

```
<body>
   <h1>Foo</h1>
   <div>a</div>
   <div>b</div>
   <h4>Bar</h4>
   <div>c</div>
   <div id="wrap-until"></div>
</body>
```

I can wrap the whole of the body section easily using `$('body').wrapInner('<div class="content"></div>');` **but** how can I wrap the body content up until my **wrap-until** div element, so it looks like:

```
<body>
   <div class="content">
      <h1>Foo</h1>
      <div>a</div>
      <div>b</div>
      <h4>Bar</h4>
      <div>c</div>
   </div>
   <div id="wrap-until"></div>
</body>
```

**Note:** The content inside the body will always be different but the **#wrap-until** element will always be available.

Comment: Sorry @RoryMcCrossan I think the wrapper element confused things, I've updated the question to not have the wrapper.

Comment: Ah ok, no problem. I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab all the required elements and use `not()` to exclude the `wrap-until` element then `wrapAll()`, like this:

```
$('body > *').not('#wrap-until').wrapAll('<div class="content"></div>');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ha8gnx5w/)

Comment: Great solution, my only question is how intensive this is to use due to the asterisk and the need to go through all body elements, although I suspect that using the > limits this to only top level elements that it should be ok?

Comment: That is a concern, but given the HTML structure in your OP there is unfortunately no alternative. If you could manually add a class to all the required elements it would improve performance, but I'm guessing if you could edit the HTML you wouldn't need to do this in the first place :) Performance with this should be fine though. You're correct that the `>` operator is restricting the selector to children of `body` only.

Comment: As it is only used once on page load and has no need to re-run on page clicks or with interactive elements etc. I think the performance will be fine. You're right, if I had access to the HTML this would be a much easier fix! Thanks again for the help, I had been tearing my hair out over something that in the end was so simple and elegant :-)